# Velocity vector for constant acceleration in newtonian mechanics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, velocity

If the acceleration vector of an object remains constant, is there no change in the direction of the velocity vector?

The question applies to any movements in classical physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if the initial velocity is in the same direction as the acceleration. Otherwise, no.

To see why, for constant acceleration ${\bf{a}} = a {\bf{\hat{a}}}$ (both $a = \left|{\bf{a}}\right|$ and ${\bf{\hat{a}}} = {\bf{a}}/a$ are constant) and initial velocity $v_0 {\bf{\hat{b}}}$, the velocity at time $t$ is
$$
{\bf{v}}\left(t\right) = {\bf{v}}\left(0\right) + {\bf{a}} t = v_0 {\bf{\hat{b}}} + at \ {\bf{\hat{a}}}.
$$
If ${\bf{\hat{a}}} = {\bf{\hat{b}}}$, ${\bf{v}}\left(t\right) = \left(v_0 + at\right) {\bf{\hat{a}}}$. Since ${\bf{\hat{a}}}$ is constant, so is the direction of ${\bf{v}}\left(t\right)$.

If ${\bf{\hat{a}}} \ne {\bf{\hat{b}}}$, so that ${\bf{\hat{a}}} \bullet {\bf{\hat{b}}} = \cos \theta$, with $\theta \ne 0$ the angle between ${\bf{\hat{a}}}$ and ${\bf{\hat{b}}}$, the magnitude of the velocity is
$$
\left|{\bf{v}}\left(t\right)\right| = \sqrt{{\bf{v}}\left(t\right) \bullet {\bf{v}}\left(t\right)} = \sqrt{v_0^2 + a^2 t^2 + 2 v_0 a t \cos \theta}
$$
and the direction is
$$
\frac{{\bf{v}}\left(t\right)}{\left|{\bf{v}}\left(t\right)\right|} = \frac{v_0 {\bf{\hat{b}}} + at \ {\bf{\hat{a}}}}{\sqrt{v_0^2 + a^2 t^2 + 2 v_0 a t \cos \theta}},
$$
which is not constant for $\theta \ne 0$ (take its time derivative to be sure, if you want).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's a homework question.

Anyway, the answer is no. Think of a projectile shot horizontaly (acceleration points downwards, but velocity is changing).

Comment: Is not a homework question, my girlfriend have this question that i can't give a answer, cause i have doubt with a circular motion. I just say that, but if the motion is circular a vector speed changes it's direction.

Comment: I just gave an example where constant acceleration makes velocity's direction change. But in the case of circular motion, acceleration's direction varies.

Comment: Ok, speed direction varies in the circular motion?

Comment: @LuizFilipe Sure! A circle is quite different from a straight line, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

No, if the velocity and acceleration vectors are not parallel, then the velocity vector will change.

### Example

At $t=0$ velocity is $\vec{v}(0)=(1,0,0)$ and acceleration is $\vec{a}=(0,0,1)$. Later the velocity is

$$\vec{v}(t) = (1,0,t)$$ which varies by magnitude and direction.

Comment: Please be precise, velocity vector change whenever acceleration vector is not 0

Comment: I think you mean the direction of the velocity vector.

Comment: Look at the simple example. Do you understand now?

Comment: I meant $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{a}$ not parallel $\implies$ change of $\vec{v}$, but it's more specific to say  $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{a}$ not parallel $\iff$ the direction of $\vec{v}$ changes.